# DirectShow error causing non function WebCam

Tags: windows, webcam, directx, directshow

Recently, I found out none of my application can detect my webcam anymore (which works without any issue before). I have tried to reinstall the webcam driver and my device manager can see my webcam working properly in its list, but no other application can detect an webcam is connected. I try to use a tools [camdiag](http://download.cnet.com/Webcam-Diagnostics/3000-2348_4-10504755.html) (which suggest from the skype forum) to see if the webcam itself have any problem. However, after the app itself can found the webcam and can connect the cam successfully. The odd part is that it is the only application which can successfully connect to my webcam while other like Skype, hangout, VirtualDub etc cannot.

After I dig into deeper, I found out that there may be some issue regarding to my DirectShow. I run DxDiag and I get this error
[DxDiag Error Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi3Kv.png)

But when I click "Run 64-bit DxDiag" button, I didn't get that DirectShow error. I try to do a google "Problem getting DirectShow Info", but nothing really come out.

Anyone ever experience such issue and how can I fix the direct show issue? I try to reinstall the Windows 7 SDK but without luck. Some of my game using Windows Media Framework also failed to run to (again, it also happen only recently).